# (Semantic UI) How to make a fixed vertical left side menu

Tags: semantic-ui

I want to make a menu fixed to the left side.

I tried `sidebar`, it seems good at first but soon I realize the content in the `pusher` cannot be shown fully if the content is wider than the screen (and there is no scrollbar).

```
<body>
  <div class="ui visible left vertical menu sidebar">
    <a class="item">Item 1</a>
    <a class="item">Item 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    a very long sentence, a very long sentence, a very long sentence, a very long sentence, 
  </div>
</body>
```

If I delete the `pusher` class the wide contents get shown but now the `sidebar` covers some contents, which is not a surprise. It seems in Semantic UI the sidebar is designed to be hidden so that contents in the `pusher` will be fully shown.

What is the "right" way to make a fixed left side vertical menu? or is there any way to have contents in the `pusher` fully seen(even a scrollbar is helpful)?

Answer (score 0):

I've inspect what you described and I have an answer for your *"What is the "right" way to make a fixed left side vertical menu?"* question.
Here is the HTML;

```
    <div class="ui top attached demo menu">
  <a class="item">
    <i class="sidebar icon"></i> Menu
  </a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
  <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical demo sidebar menu">
    <a class="item">
      <i class="home icon"></i> Home
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="block layout icon"></i> Topics
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="smile icon"></i> Friends
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="calendar icon"></i> History
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="ui basic segment">
      <h3 class="ui header">Application Content</h3>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Here is the JavaScript;

```
    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
    context: $('.bottom.segment')
  })
  .sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item');
```

For detail you can review this code snippet;
https://codepen.io/redshift7/pen/VaKmjq

Hope you will handle it!